# SQL LEFT JOIN with where clause from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, outer-join

I am trying to join two columns and where condition is based on Delete and Active column in right table.

Query ->

```
SELECT
    `s`.`slider_id` as `id`,
    `s`.`slider_type` as `type`,
    `s`.`slider_name` as `name`,
    `sd`.`slider_data_type` AS `sd_type`,
    `sd`.`slider_data_value` AS `sd_value`,
    `sd`.`slider_data_group` AS `sd_group`,
    `sd`.`slider_data_id` AS `sd_id`
FROM `sliders` AS `s`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `slider_data` AS `sd`
    ON `s`.`slider_id` = `sd`.`slider_data_s_id`
WHERE
    `s`.`slider_id` = '11' AND
    ( ( `sd`.`slider_data_active` = 1 AND `sd`.`slider_data_delete` =0 ) OR
      ( `sd`.`slider_data_active` IS NULL AND `sd`.`slider_data_delete` IS NULL ) )
```

Query is working fine when there is no record in another or RIGHT table with matching condition. But not when

```
`sd`.`slider_data_active` = 0 AND `sd`.`slider_data_delete` = 1
```

I want to still retrieve data from main or left table when active column and delete column in right table is 0 and 1

Active 0 and delete 1 will be equal to NULL in right column

any workaround please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `AND` Condition in `WHERE` clause to table joining condition (`ON`), When you use `LEFT JOINED` table in `WHERE` clause then its start behaving like `INNER JOIN` and only give result when there is exact match found.

```
SELECT `s`.`slider_id` as `id`, `s`.`slider_type` as `type`, `s`.`slider_name` as `name`, `sd`.`slider_data_type` AS `sd_type`, `sd`.`slider_data_value` AS `sd_value`, `sd`.`slider_data_group` AS `sd_group`, `sd`.`slider_data_id` AS `sd_id` 
FROM `sliders` AS `s` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `slider_data` AS `sd` ON `s`.`slider_id` = `sd`.`slider_data_s_id` AND ( ( `sd`.`slider_data_active` = 1 AND `sd`.`slider_data_delete` =0 ) OR ( `sd`.`slider_data_active` IS NULL AND `sd`.`slider_data_delete` IS NULL ) )
WHERE `s`.`slider_id` = '11'
```